# How can I automatically generate a url for a specific item in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, django, angular

For example i have different items from the database and would like to share a link that will let someone to specific item only without showing other related items, eg i have football, volleyball among others, so you are playing football, you should get a link to take you to football page to register there.

Comment: dynamic ID, ActivatedRoute parmas

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It can be done in many different ways depending on your design choice. U can use query parameters, resolvers, or even different URLs for different products.